# how can i change the color in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I havehttps://i.stack.imgur.com/JRm2K.png a plot in R which produced with ggplot2, I want to change the color from the left side to the right side,https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOYVj.png. how can I change the color to a blue pallete?
thank you

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You can provide your data via the output of `dput(df)` or to give a minimal subset use `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: One difference between the actual plot and the wanted plot is that injSeverity is a factor and not a number. When using factors there is a discontinuous color palette chosen by default in ggplot2. If you can provide a reproducible example, as @Andrew Gillreath-Brown suggested already, I could work further on that issue. This means. 1) please provide an example of the data 2) please provide your code for plotting. It is more likely to get a helpful answer when the question is nicely (-> clear and reproducible) asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a palette.  Lots of examples here - one of which should suit your needs - https://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually

Comment: I know it's not the best to post a link - but is it better to post nothing if time is short, or a link that provides a solution?

Comment: i just want to know how to change the color from rainbow to blue pallet, I tried everything, the color is the same!

Comment: You could try:
`require(RColorBrewer)
# Box plot
bp + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")`

(Where bp is your existing plot variable)

Comment: DId this solve your problem?

Comment: yes, I checked it now, it worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Like the first comment on your question says it is a bit hard to help without any data and/or code example.
Based on the question the best answer would probably be scale_fill_manual().
your boxplot code = bp

```
bp + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#999999", "#999999", "#999999", "#999999", "#999999"))
```

Use a hexidecimal color map to find the colors you want and replace the 9's with the hexidecimal code you want.